# I cannot update my array state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code, can't figure out why this doesn't udpate my react state?

```
state = {
    popUpMessages:[]
  }
  popUpMessage(id,name) {
    console.log("id ",id,"name ",name)
    const addUserObject = { id, name };
    const newArray = [...this.state.popUpMessages, addUserObject]
    console.log("newArray = ",newArray)
    this.setState({ popUpMessages: newArray });
  }
```

In this code popUpMessage gets invoked to update the state:

```
<li  onClick={() => this.popUpMessage(this.props.id,this.props.name)}>{this.props.name}</li>
```

but my state is not updating and when I try to log, the previous user object is removed? I want my state to be array of objects something like this:

```
[{id:1, name: kim bok joo},{id:2, name: ria atayde}]
```

Comment: You have to bind your onClick function, popUpMessage, because it's not in the scope of your class to contain this.props.id or this.props.name; it's in the scope of the onClick function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, not exactly recommended to do it this way. However, if you want to do it this way, this is all you have to do.

```
  popUpMessage(id,name) {
    const addUserObject = { id, name };
    const newArray = this.state.popUpMessages.concat([addUserObject])
    this.setState({ popUpMessages: newArray });
  }
```

Comment: Is it the same issue? The previous object is removed from the array? are you binding the method? This piece of code here `<li  onClick={() => this.popUpMessage(this.props.id,this.props.name)}>{this.props.name}</li>` should be `<li  onClick={() => this.popUpMessage(this.props.id,this.props.name).bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</li>` unless you've bound it up at the top inside your constructor.

Comment: this is weird, I have this returned: 
id:{id: 1, name: "ria atayde"}
name:{}

Comment: Ok well make sure you are getting the correct values that you are looking to pass. Are your `console.log()` statements returning what you expect? Once you're able to `console.log()` --> `{id:2, name: ria atayde}` - try my original snippet of code and see if that works.

Comment: my bad, I was updating each childs' state :( what a waste of time

Answer (score 2):

[The docs say](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) that you should not depend on previous value of `this.state` when computing the new state.

But you do: `const newArray = [...this.state.popUpMessages, addUserObject]`

Try using a function that accepts the previous state and works with props, as shown in the docs.

Comment: can I ask for a code help? I was trying to do that to copy the properties so I am treating the state as immutable

Comment: It is the right idea to treat the state as immutable. The idea is that you should give `.setState` _a function_, not an object, and it will be called with the right then-current state when updates are calculated. That function should return the update to the state as an object.